# Session Variable with if/else statement in Views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, user-controls, session-variables

I want to include an ascx file with navigator bar. There are two versions, one shows up when user is not logged in and one is for logged user.

This is what I'm lookin for

```
<div class="navigator">
<%
if(Session["loggedin"] == null) {
    Include this file <uc1:nav runat="server" ID="nav" />
} else {
    Include this file <uc1:nav runat="server" ID="nav2" />
}
%>
</div>
```

This is how I can link one of the nav... but I have no idea how to make this path into if/else statment

Tried to do some things inside of <% %> but.... without any success.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: describe your problem clearly

Comment: what is your error, mvc version

Comment: @anand I do not have any error yet, cause I have no idea how to include it like in shown exampple  Im working on VS 2015, web forms c#

Comment: when user logged in did you assign data to `Session["loggedin"]`

Answer (score 0):

Appeareantly I figured it out.
Here is what I did.

```
  <% if(Session["loggedin"] == null) { %>

      <uc1:nav runat="server" ID="nav" />

  <% } else { %>

       <uc1:nav runat="server" ID="nav2" />

  <% } %>
```